# Prevent page refresh on navigation with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im working in an MVC 5 project and i want to change my content using ajax

```
<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {

        window.onpopstate = function (e) {
            if (e.state) {
                $('.body-content').html(e.state.html);
                document.title = e.state.pageTitle;
            }
        };


        $("a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); \\ currently placed here, but 
            var me = $(this);
            $('.body-content').fadeOut(300, function () {

                var url = "" + me.attr("href");

                if (!url || url.match("^http")) {
                    debugger;
                    return true;
                }
                if (!url || url === "/") {
                    url = "Home/Index";
                }
                $('.body-content').load(url, function () {

                    $('.body-content').fadeIn(300);
                    //window.history.pushState(
                    //    null,
                    //    'Terram Novum', // new page title
                    //    url// new url
                    //);
                });
                return false;
            });




        });

    });
</script>
```

this is the code that I've written so far, but sometimes it still refreshes sometimes and i can not figure out a pattern or reason.

The code is placed in the _layout.cshtml page and I havent changed much from the template. Can anyone helpt me out or figure out a better way to do this?

oh and bonus points if you can help me figure out when im going from one area to another.

Answer (score 0):

This code only works on your first page load, because it's placed in $(document).ready(), but subsequently, once you have left the first page and in another page with links, you'll have to attach the event listener to all your  tags again, because they weren't there initially.

Comment: true, but once i leave my menu in. So those should be registered. But after a few page switches it still refreshes.